# ManagedObjectModel inits to nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Just creating a new iPhone application with CoreData. My application builds without any warnings or errors and has my .xcdatamodeld in it as well which has no errors or warnings.

For some reason my managedObjectModel won't initialise and I can't work out why.

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
 if (__managedObjectModel) {
     return __managedObjectModel;
}

 NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"BAK" withExtension:@"momd"];
 __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
 return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

The modelURL resolves correctly and points to my compiled data model but the managedObjectModel stays at nil after its alloc line. There is no output into the console either. What can cause this or what am I missing?

The __managedObjectModel is declared as follows:

```
.h
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
.m
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how are you declaring your managedObjectModel iVars? ... are you using properties? EDIT:  I should be more clear.  Your instance variable _managedObjectModel should have some attributes, eg, strong weak, copy, etc.  Can you please update your question to include how you are declaring this in your .h or .m file.

Comment: Updated! Hope this helps. I think it might be some sort of corruption or something in the xcdatamodel as adding a new version to it fixes the problem. I would like to know what is wrong with the original version however

Comment: hmmm, I was thinking maybe you weren't keeping a strong pointer to it and hence it was being dealloc'd from the heap but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Not sure what is going on here.  Glad to hear updating the model file helps.  Sorry I couldn't be more of a help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is you changed the model somehow, most likely the name ("BAK" to something else or something else to "BAK").

That initialization of the NSManagedObjectModel is really simple.  If it has been initialized and exists, return it, otherwise initialize the ManagedObjectModel using the name you provided ("BAK").

The only other explanation is that somehow, someway, the Core Data model didn't get initialized in the main bundle location, but somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah I ended up deleting and remaking the model and it works now. Who knows what happened to the other one. Thanks for your help